# There is no algorithm which has a runtime of $O(n^2)$ and $\Theta(n^\frac{7}{2})$

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

How can I proof that there exists no algorithm which has a runtime of $O(n^2)$ and $\theta(n^{\frac{7}{2}})$?

Or is this possible because logically I would say that if a function is $O(n^{\frac{7}{2}})$ then it is also $O(n^2)$.

Comment: I believe your assumption is wrong: $O(n^2) \implies O(n^\frac{7}{2})$ but not the converse, like you've said.

Comment: How can I proof that there exists such algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $n^{3.5}>n^{2}$ for $n>1$

Comment: I guess the problem must be with the $\Omega$? The problem is with the lower limit...it will at some point exceed the $n^2$.

Comment: You can not say that the runtime is $O(n^2)$ and also to say that the runtime is $\Theta (n^{3.5})$ because $n^{3.5}>n^2$, as you know big $O$ is upper bound